# Make Google Forms in plain text?

Tags: google-forms

I'm looking for a way of creating Google Forms with some sort of plain text syntax and then uploading it to Drive. Are there any addons that might make that possible?

If that's not something that exists, does anyone know how to make form creation go quicker? The web interface is too clunky for me.

Comment: Google Forms has an [API service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) that you can use to programmatically create forms using a text editor rather than the web interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on called: doc to form
You can easily create a form using Google Docs and after that the add-on will generate the form.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/doc-to-form/paadgjaehgkbopbjfaomaophiphlmalh?authuser=0

There is a demo on YouTube: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bc2mdj4kVJg